# Angular 8 Display preview of two image input

Tags: html, angular, image, file, upload

I have two input of uploading image and I want to display a preview of those two, for one input it works correctly !

```
<div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
              <label for="">Icon</label>
              <input style="display: none" type="file" (change)="onIconChanged($event)" #fileInput>
              <div class="card-img-top"
                [style.background]="displayIcon ? 'url(' + displayIcon + ')' : 'url(http://via.placeholder.com/100x100)'"
                style="width: 100px;height: 100px;"></div>
              <button type="button" class="buupload" (click)="fileInput.click()">Upload</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
              <label for="">Banner</label>
              <input style="display: none" type="file" (change)="onBannerChanged($event)" #fileInput>
              <div class="card-img-top"
                [style.background]="displayBanner ? 'url(' + displayBanner + ')' : 'url(http://via.placeholder.com/550x100)'"
                style="width: 550px;height: 100px;"></div>
              <button type="button" class="buupload" (click)="fileInput.click()">Upload</button>
            </div>
```

** ts **

```
onIconChanged(event) {
    this.selectedIcon = event.target.files[0]
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => this.displayIcon = reader.result;

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }

  onBannerChanged(event) {
    this.selectedBanner = event.target.files[1]
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[1]) {
      const file = event.target.files[1];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => this.displayBanner = reader.result;

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```

the display of banner input not working and it always appears on the first  input preview (icon) !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the second input referance and try again.

```
 <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
              <label for="">Banner</label>
              <input style="display: none" type="file" (change)="onBannerChanged($event)" #secondFileInput>
              <div class="card-img-top"
                [style.background]="displayBanner ? 'url(' + displayBanner + ')' : 'url(http://via.placeholder.com/550x100)'"
                style="width: 550px;height: 100px;"></div>
              <button type="button" class="buupload" (click)="secondFileInput.click()">Upload</button>
            </div>
```